# how to print items of sub array using map function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, database, dictionary

This is the code i am trying to print out the comments through map function but cant figure out how:

```
class Postcomment2 extends React.Component {
uploadcomment = () => {
  return this.props.post.comments.map((commentz) => {
    return <div>{this.props.post.comments["comment"]}</div>;
  }); /* How to access sub array of comments and print them all */
};

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{this.uploadcomment()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

in this Post is the array of objects and the data is:

```
{
imageUrl:
  "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/83/6c/8a/836c8a66349fecbc0a06c4cc3d41e031.jpg",
user: Users[0].user,
likes: 410,
caption:
  "Here at kingdom tower... #KSA #KingdomTower #React JS #This is getting too long #Peace",
profilepic: Users[0]["image"],
comments: [
  {
    user: "zoraiz",
    comment: "Nicee!"
  },
  {
    user: "asher",
    comment: "Alrightttt!!"
  },
  {
    user: "hamis",
    comment: "Interesting...."
  }
]
```

},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
uploadcomment = () => {
    const { comments } = this.props.post;

    return (
      <div>
         {comments.map(comment => {
             console.log(comment.user, comment.comment)
             return true;
         })}
      </div>
    )
```

This should now print out every comment's user and comment. Change the return to whatever JSX you wish to render.

Before, you were mapping over the comments, and every iteration you got 'commentz' which you weren't even using inside of the map. This is the current 'comment' in the iteration of the map, so you basically have access to it and it's properties such as `user` and `comment`.

When you tried to do `this.props.post.comments["comment"]` previously, this was saying basically, every iteration, get comments.comment, however, comments is an array not an object.

Comment: No worries. If you don't understand any syntax I used or why I did it as I changed it slightly let me know :)

Comment: Im sorry i know this is a dumb question but could you tell why is { comments } in brackets?

Comment: Not dumb, I felt like you may ask. So basically this is called object destructuring. `this.props.post` is an object right, with key: value pairs. So it's just an alternative syntax (much cleaner IMO) than doing `this.props.post.comments`. It's saying, get the key out of the post object. You can also do multiple, like, { comments, user, likes } etc. Which also lets you take out multiple values out the object you want one on line instead of repeating `this.props.post` and on multiple lines. Hope that made sense :)

Comment: OHHH my god thanks so much mann now i wont have to waste so much time  on this.props..... thanks alot! :D

Comment: No worries, it is really cool and useful :D. There's also array destructuring which is cool in some cases. For example `const [a, b] = [10, 20]` instead of `const a = [10, 20][0]; const b = [10, 20][1]` :)

Comment: :OOOOOOOOOOOOOO

Answer (score 1):

You need to first Traverse the `Post` array and after that traverse the subArray `comment`. Please find the [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/traverse-sub-arrays-tqif31) link